# Recursion Question with Valid Parenthesis

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I am trying to understand this solution for generating all valid parentheses.

The part I don't understand is how the recursion can find ALL of the different combinations. When I debug through the code, I put a watch on the integers "left" and "right." With the input of 2 in generateParenthesis, after "ans" is populated with 1 valid parenthesis, at "return ans" I see the variable "right" decrease making the if statement "right < left" valid. How does the variable "right" decrease like that when I never specifically set it to do so? To put it simply, how is recursion able to find all the cases of valid parenthesis, not just one in this situation?

Below I included the question along with an online Python Debugger to see what I'm talking about.
https://onlinegdb.com/LMNYtq3iR

https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/

```
def generateParenthesis(N):
   ans = []
   S = ''
   left = 0
   right = 0
   ans = backtrack(N, S, left, right, ans)

def backtrack(N, S, left, right, ans):
   print(left)
   if len(S) == 2 * N:
      ans.append(S)
   if left < N:
      backtrack(N, S+'(', left+1, right, ans)
   if right < left:
    backtrack(N, S+')', left, right+1, ans)

   return ans
    
generateParenthesis(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable right does *never* decrease. You see the value of an earlier recursive execution. It may become clearer if you include the current recursion level in the output:

```
print(" "*len(S), S, left, right)

  0 0
  ( 1 0
   (( 2 0
    (() 2 1
     (()) 2 2
   () 1 1   <-- left and right do not decrease, this is the call after `( 1 0` above
    ()( 2 1
     ()() 2 2
```

On an unrelated note, you are using `return` inconsistently here. The `backtrack` function does not have to `return` at all, since it adds elements to the `ans` parameter, and the `generateParenthesis` does not return at all. I'd suggest dropping the `ans` parameter and changing the function to be a proper generator function instead:

```
def generateParenthesis(N):
   return backtrack(N, S="", left=0, right=0)

def backtrack(N, S, left, right):
   print(" "*len(S), S, left, right)
   if len(S) == 2 * N:
       yield S
   if left < N:
       yield from backtrack(N, S+'(', left+1, right)
   if right < left:
       yield from backtrack(N, S+')', left, right+1)
    
print(list(generateParenthesis(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way in which frames work in Python. Walking through the execution of the program, we essentially start with backtrack called with the variables possessing values from generateParanthesis, and then since left is less than N, we get a recursive call to backtrack, left is iterated, and the program continues along that line, following the recursive call. So you open a bunch of new frames, do a bunch of different operations, before the program even gets to the next line, finds right and left are equal in that frame, and returns the answer. You are seeing something similar occur; essentially you go into a later frame, and then once that frame is closed, return to an earlier frame in which right is less. Right never decreased, the program just went back to an earlier frame in which right was less. Would recommend pythontutor.com for visualizing this.